# How to use a python list to input data in a Django db?

Tags: python, django

Say I have a django model with a field.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    cat_name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
```

And I have this python script *list.py*.

```
def getList():
   name_list = ['a','b','c']
   return name_list
```

How can I call the getList to create three entries: a,b,c to be three separate Category entries in django?  Could I put them in the same dir and import the getList into one of the files in my sites dir and run it?  Or could I run it in the terminal?

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the responses everyone.  I ended up writing a script that runs a for loop through the entries, attributes it to a field in the imported model, the model to a variable x, then does x.save().  It is adhoc, but works.

Answer (score 1):

You can do either. If you're looking for something re-usable, you should consider creating an "initial_data.json" fixture that will load each time your run `syncdb`. If you're just looking for something to run once or ad-hoc, then you can do something like this, assuming everything lives in the same directory:

```
from .list import get_list


class Category(models.Model):
    cat_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.cat_name

    @classmethod
    def create_from_list(cls):
        values_list = get_list()
        for value in values_list:
            cls.objects.create(cat_name=value)
```

Then in a view, or wherever, you can execute the classmethod:

```
# views.py

from .models import Category


def my_view(request):
    Category.create_from_list()
    ...
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/initial-data/ for more information about fixtures.

Comment: Or you can use a model manager to to do this by creating a similar method as in Brandon's example that will accept a list and then create the instances of Category by iterating through the list. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/

Answer (score 0):

You can use bulk_create method https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

In your case:

```
Category.objects.bulk_create([Category(cat_name=name) for name in getList()])
```